# BLE Lilypad simblee Android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm extremely new to android app development, and I'm attempting to write a Bluetooth application to communicate with a BLE peripheral (Lilypad Simblee). I want the app to establish a connection with the already paired peripheral at launch, and once that's done I want the app to look for a specific characteristic using a custom 128bit uuid which I configured on the peripheral and display the data from that characteristic in a textview.

I looked at android's BluetoothLeGratt example code and this what i have so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
private boolean mConnected = false;
//Textview to identify state as connected or disconnected
private TextView mConnectionState;
//Textview to display data from characteristic
private TextView mDataField;
String  mDeviceAddress;
public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME = "DEVICE_NAME";
public static final String EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "DEVICE_ADDRESS";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mNotifyCharacteristic;
private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>> mGattCharacteristics =
        new ArrayList<ArrayList<BluetoothGattCharacteristic>>();

private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        String intentAction;
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            intentAction = "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
            //mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
             mConnectionState.setText("Connected");;
            broadcastUpdate(intentAction);

            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();


        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            intentAction = "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
            //mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
            mConnectionState.setText("Disconnected");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            mConnectionState.setText("Connected");
        } else {
            mConnectionState.setText("Disonnected");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
             broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
    }
};

private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            finish();
        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect("E8:FF:34:49:A9:5B");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = true;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            mConnected = false;
            updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
            //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            //clearUI();
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
            //displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
            displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDataField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
    if(!BA.isEnabled()){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable Bluetooth in phone settings.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        //startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
        }

    mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connection_state);
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, filter1);
    registerReceiver( mGattUpdateReceiver, filter2);
    final BluetoothDevice device = BA.getRemoteDevice("E8:FF:34:49:A9:5B");


    mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);



    //mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unbindService(mServiceConnection);
    mBluetoothLeService = null;
}


private void updateConnectionState(final int resourceId) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mConnectionState.setText(resourceId);
        }
    });
}


private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

// For lilypad profile, writes data
private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                             final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    if ("c97433f0-be8f-4dc8-b6f0-5343e6100eb4".equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {

        long data = characteristic.getIntValue(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT32, 0);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, data);
    }

    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}

private void displayData(String data) {
    if (data != null) {
        mDataField.setText(data);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with that code exactly?

Comment: The textview doesn't get updated with the data, i don't even know if i'm actually connected to the bonded device or if i'm properly reading the characteristic to display the data.

Comment: if you run any UI related code in UIThread it should work, BluetoothGattCallback methods doesn't run on UI Thread. Use runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 mConnectionState.setText("Disconnected");
            }
        });

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed to get it working by broadcasting an intent with the data, and displaying it with intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA).
But now i'm trying to connect to another peripheral, and i'm doing this by calling mBluetoothLeService.connect for the second device once the phone has succesfuly connected to the GATT server. My problem now is each device broadcast intent overlap the other, the textview gets overwritten with the other device's data whenever data is to be read.